# CRM4 Rollup 5 worth the upgrade?

Tags: patch-management, microsoft-dynamics-crm, crm

I have a Microsoft CRM 4.0 application that has been fairly customized.  We have not installed any CRM rollup's. Is it going to be worthwhile to upgrade with the rollup 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my users was getting very poor performance, and getting a lot of small errors in the system log about various CRM issues. I installed roll-up 5 and they have really quieted down. However this is just one admin talking, take it with a grain of salt. Perhaps install it on a test system have a power user play around with it.